# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("tr :odd").attr("class" : "dark"),
       $("tr :even").attr("class" : "light")
    });
</script>
```

This is the code I am using to give classes to rows in a table.
For some reason, It keeps throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: `:` is used in object literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a **really good** practice to end every sentence with a semicolon.

The problem is that you use `attr` function wrong. 
It takes two plain values (key and value) or a JS object as a single argument.

Key-value:

```
$("tr :odd").attr("class", "dark");
$("tr :even").attr("class", "light");
```

Object:

```
$("tr :odd").attr({"class": "dark"}); // Usually for multiple values
$("tr :even").attr({"class": "light"}); // Usually for multiple values
```

Moreover, changing class through `attr` is a **really bad practice**.

Use jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` functions:

```
$("tr:odd").addClass("dark");
$("tr:even").addClass("light");
```

And, finally, are you sure you really need this?

You have CSS like:

```
.dark 
{
    background-color: #333333;
}

.light
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

You can do it this way:

```
.tr:nth-chlid(odd)
{
    background-color: #333333;
}

.tr:nth-chlid(even)
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

It is great to avoid using scripts whenever it is possible.

Comment: semicolon is _optional_!

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped. and css code should be tr:nth-child(odd) and not tr:odd but thanks for the idea.. helped a lot

Comment: Wanted to know why did u suggest the we should avoid using scripts whenever it is possible? @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: @krishna Nice to hear it. Thanks. I have corrected an answer in order to not confuse other people who will read it.

Comment: @krishna Oh. It's, imho, firstly, about performance. For example, in your case - it will "color" table rows only after a document is loaded. In case of CSS, a browser will draw tables rows colored already. It is also about debugging - you, obviously, don't need to debug CSS; and it becomes easier to debug your JS as there are few lines of code :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this (using an object literal):

```
$(selector).attr({"class": "dark"})
```

or

```
$(selector).attr("class", "dark")
```